# How to build a docker container in eclipse-temurin with maven?

Tags: java, docker

I'm starting to build a java application container with docker. I'd like to build the `jar` directly inside the docker container itself. But the following always fails. Why?

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM eclipse-temurin:11 as build
WORKDIR application

COPY .mvn .mvn
```

Comment: You can check: https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/eclipse-temurin-17/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11 as build
```